# Corpscon6 reliability

Tags: elevation

I've been blindly using Corpscon to convert from NGVD29 to NAVD88.  Have any of you kind folks found issues with your outputs?

Answer (score 2):

CorpsCon [has a help FAQ](http://www.mvn.usace.army.mil/ed/edss/faqs.asp#CONVERT1) for issues surrounding NGVD29 to NAVD88 conversion, and specifically mentions:

**Can’t I use CorpsCon to convert survey data from NGVD29 to NAVD88?**

> In Missouri, yes; but in Louisiana,
>   absolutely NOT! The NAVD88 was
>   developed as a replacement for the
>   NGVD29 because the NGVD29 had become
>   unreliable and out-of-date. The NAVD88
>   was published for most of the country
>   by 1990, except for those regions of
>   known crustal motion which included
>   Louisiana. In 1992, the NAVD88 was
>   published for Louisiana, but because
>   of the continuing crustal motion of
>   subsidence the lifespan of the NAVD88
>   benchmark elevations in Louisiana was
>   limited to a few years.

That said, depending on the accuracy needed, you may be able to test your results against something like this [modeled conversion from NOAA](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/VERTCON/vert_con.prl).